# Adding value to singly-linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm in a C++ data structures class and a recent homework assignment has been bugging me for days. It has to deal with working with singly-linked lists, and one of the methods we have to write has to do with adding values to the list.

First off, we create the dummy node `head`:

```
template<typename T>
SLList<T>::SLList()
{
  head = new Node; // Node() is ok too
}
```

If I'm correct, this shouldn't hold a value, should it? So head should be `NULL`. This is what I've managed to create (with my professor's help) so far.

```
template<typename T>
void SLList<T>::add(const T& val) {
    bool duplicate = false;
    //Node *ptr = head->next;
    //cout << head->data;

    for (Node *ptr = head->next; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
    //while (ptr == NULL) {
        //ptr = ptr->next;
        // if ptr is initialized as head, the first node, then ptr != NULL
        // if ptr is initialized as head->next, which it should in order to
        // traverse from the node AFTER the head, then ptr == NULL
        // not exactly sure why.
        if (ptr->data == val) {
            duplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //Node *temp = new Node(val); // create new node with new element.
    //temp->next = ptr->next;
    //ptr->next = temp;

    if (duplicate) {
        cout << "Duplicate entry found: " << val << endl;
    }
}
```

I've tried working with `for` and `while` loops, since a lot of google results used `while` loops in their answers. What I'm trying to do is attempt to add a value to the list. If the value is already in that list, it doesn't get added. I'm attempting this with:

```
SLList<int> iList;
iList.add(5);
iList.add(6);
iList.add(6);
```

When I asked for help, I was told that I should initialize `*ptr` as `head->next` to start traversing the list for the node AFTER the dummy node. I used Visual Studio's debugger and found that after initializing it to `head->next` the program never went into the for loop, which I'm assuming is because the node after the dummy node fails the if statement `ptr != NULL`. I'm not exactly sure why that is, as when I had `Node *ptr = head` it would traverse through the list just fine (although the following line `if (ptr->data == val)` would consider every entry a duplicate entry).

I'm probably understanding this wrong, but shouldn't the `head` node have a value of `NULL`? So it shouldn't pass the `if` statement in the `for` loop.

There also seems to be a problem with the three lines after the `for` loop, since when the program gets down there, it just crashes and fails to add any values to the list, but I figured I'd just take it one step at a time.

There's probably a lot here I'm misunderstanding, so any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: `head` certainly should NOT be NULL. The new operator does not return null pointers. It's just that it's data values will not have good data in them, since it's just a dummy node.

Comment: @ooga Oh I see.. So there is data, just not any good data? I just figured `NULL` would be the same as `0`.

Comment: `head` itself can't be NULL (which is kind of the same as 0). It must point to a valid `Node` object, so `head` will have a valid (non-null) address in it. But the data in the `Node` that it points to is arbitrary since it's just a "dummy node", as you've said.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void SLList<T>::add(const T& val) {
    Node<T>* prev = head;
    for (Node<T>* ptr = head->next; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        if (ptr->data == val) {
            std::cout << "Duplicate: " << val << '\n';
            return;
        }
        prev = ptr;
    }
    prev->next = new Node<T>(val);
}
```

Comment: I'm combining this with Elayeek's answer above, so I'm guessing that we're checking to see if there is a `ptr` value in the foor loop. If so, we run the duplicate check, then `prev` becomes whatever `ptr` is, so does `head = ptr`?

Answer (score 1):

Your main design flaw here seems to be this:
You're going to the end of your list and taking it from there but the end is null so you need to backtrack once to find something that is not null.
For instance (basic example)

```
Node<T>* last = head;
for(Node<T>* ptr = head->next; ptr != NULL ; ptr = ptr->next){
    last = ptr;
    //do something
}
```

So when the loop is over, you know that if `ptr==NULL` then `last` is the tail of your list and anything you want to add must follow it.

This is also the problem in the three lines of code after the `for` loop:
If I am understanding you correctly, in the case that there is no duplicate, you are iterating until `ptr` is `NULL`. So when exiting the for, `ptr->next` will fail.
This means that when adding an element, if that element is not in the list - your function fails (by design and not by accident).

Comment: So instead of letting `head` just float around, we're assigning it to `last` and going through the loop, right? Then if `ptr != NULL` it'll go into the `for` loop and assign `ptr` to `last` and just constantly update that until `ptr == NULL`? Then if so (combining this with ooga's answer below) assuming there is no duplicate, `prev->next` (which I believe will really be `ptr->next` will create a new Node with the value? There's a chance I'm over complicating this though.

Comment: Well, ooga's answer is actually just a complete solution.
I gave you only partial solution because I was explaining the concept.

But it is prev->next (in my solution, last->next) because ptr is always one ahead of last (prev in ooga's solution) so if ptr is one past the end of the list, last (or prev) is the last node.
In the event that the node is only the head, it will skip the for loop and add a new node (in ooga's solution that is, my comment is mostly explanatory)

Answer (score 0):

### HEAD

When the list is empty, head must be NULL. This happens at creation or after adding and deleting equal number of nodes. In all other situations, head must be non-NULL, and it must point to the first added node.

### ADD (typical)

```
Node * ptr = new Node;
ptr->next = head;
head = ptr;
```

### ADD (only non-duplicate)

```
bool const exists = std::find( list, element );
if( ! exists ) {
    Node * ptr = new Node;
    ptr->next = head;
    head = ptr;
}
```

Comment: You obviously didn't read the question since it indicates that head is a dummy node, which, of course, cannot be null.

Comment: I'm having trouble really understanding what the code does.. could you please explain? And also, in relation to checking if the list is empty, would something like `if (iList == NULL) { add head to iList)` work?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here. The most common is that you set your `head` pointer to nullptr until you add a node. In this case, you simply never had (or need) a dummy node at all.

Another possibility is to create the list initially containing a dummy node. This can simplify the rest of the code somewhat, as it avoids having any special case code for adding the first node to an empty list. You can also use the dummy node as a "sentinel", containing some data item that's not allowed throughout the rest of the list. Under the right circumstances, this can simplify list traversal by allowing you to only look at the contained data instead of ever checking for a null pointer signaling the end of the list. A prime example is a list of floating point numbers that you keep in sorted order, with the dummy node containing an `infinity`. In this case, finding a number can be simplified from:

```
while (ptr != nullptr && ptr->data < search_item) {
    // ...
    ptr=ptr->next;
}
```

...to just:

```
while (ptr->data < search_item) {
    // ...
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

The `infinity` at the end of the list ensures that if nothing else in the list is greater than `search_item`, the dummy node will be (though this obviously requires that you ensure against inserting an item into the list with `infinity` as its value).

This, however, differs from the usage you suggest in the question--it requires that the dummy node always remain as the *last* item in the list, so you never insert anything after it. At least in my experience, however, this is more common than a dummy node that's always at the beginning of the list.